# How to know the number of n_features that a model accepts?

Tags: python, unit-testing, scikit-learn, model, pickle

When you try to make a prediction using an already trained model, if the input n_features does not match the model n_features, it raises the following error:

```
ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 140 and input n_features is 130
```

What I want is to know the model n_features = 140, before it raises an error. Is there any way in which I can access the "characteristics" of the model, so I can extract the n_features value? I'm trying to build a unit test, and I need this number in order to validate.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In recent versions of sklearn, there's been a push to standardize the use of [the attribute `n_features_in_`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html#universal-attributes) for this, with `BaseEstimator` including [the method `_check_n_features`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/2218ec46227c92301ac6837c4a8ae9b8dc5d3960/sklearn/base.py#L335) for setting and checking that parameter.

So `model_variable.n_features_in_` should contain what you want, for most estimators.